# DAX Formula to Count Duplicates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the formula to count duplicate rows in Excel. It marks the first instance of a duplicate with a 1 and each duplicate thereafter with a 0.

=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2, B2)>1,0,1)

What I'm trying to write is an equivalent DAX formula that will do the same thing.

My DAX Formula is - =IF(
CALCULATE(
COUNTA(TableName[ColumnName]),
FILTER(TableName, TableName[ColumnName] = EARLIER(TableName[ColumnName]))
)>1,
0,
1
)

I'm getting this:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 0 |
| c | 0 |
| d | 1 |
| e | 1 |
| f | 0 |
| f | 0 |

What I want to achieve is this:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 0 |
| d | 1 |
| e | 1 |
| f | 1 |
| f | 0 |

Can anyone help on this

Comment: how do you define which instance is first?

Comment: usually when people do this 'identify first instance of each kind of element' in excel, it's a preparatory step for some other kind of evaluation  (Finding the earliest record in each sub-group; de-duplication, etc).  PowerBI can do a lot of these kinds of things very easily without this awkward middle-man step.  Maybe ask the bigger picture question?